# priority queue of string in c

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

This program is of priority queue where i am storing string as data and queue is created using linked list the element having least number (as priority no) has higher priority that is it will be inserted  towards head node and so while the time of removing (pop or dequeue)  that element will be removed first.(for eg 1 has higher Priority than 2)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
  char *string;
  int priority;
  struct node* next;
};
struct node *head;
struct node* getnewnode(char *s,int p){
    struct node* newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->string=s;
    newnode->priority=p;
    newnode->next=NULL;

   return newnode;
}
void push(char* str,int p){
    struct node* node1=getnewnode(str,p);
    if(head==NULL){        //if the element is inserted in empty list
      head=node1;
    }

    if(head->priority > p )
    {
      node1->next=head;
      head=node1;
    }
    else
    {
      struct node* temp=head;
      while(temp->next!=NULL&&temp->priority <= p){
        temp=temp->next;
      }
```

> `while(temp->next!=NULL&&temp->priority <= p)` is correct or not because if the pushed element priority is  matching than this new element will be placed after the present one(having same priority)

```
      node1->next=temp->next;
      temp->next=node1;

    }

}
void pop(){
    struct node* temp=head;
    head=head->next;
    free(temp);

}
char* peek(){
    return head->string;
}
int main(){
head=NULL; //head is null initially
char a[10]="akash";
push(a,1);
char b[20]="rahul";
push(b,3);
printf("%s",peek());



}
```

It is not showing desired output but it is crashing

```
int main(){
head=NULL;
char* a=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
a="akash";
push(a,1);
char* b=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
b="rahul";
push(b,3);
char* c=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
c="neymar";
push(c,1);
printf("%s",peek());
pop();
printf("%s",peek());

}
```

I give akash as priority 1 rahul as 2 and neymar again as 1 it should print akash and neymar for last two printf statements but it is printing akash rahul @dbush

Comment: When something crashes step 1 is to pop this into your debugger and find out why.

Comment: did u find any bug brother?

Comment: That's what your *debugger* is for. If you don't know how to use one, this crash is a perfect opportunity to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `push` function, in the case where `head` is NULL, you set `head` to the new node, and then later try to put the node into the list again.  You end up with the `next` field pointing to itself, so future inserts fall into an infinite loop.

When inserting into an empty list, you only need to set `head` to the new node and nothing else, so just `return` right away.

```
if(head==NULL){        //if the element is inserted in empty list
  head=node1;
  return;
}
```

Also, you should make a copy of the string that's passed in when you make a new node.  Otherwise, you could end up with a pointer to memory that is no longer valid or multiple pointers pointing to the same buffer, with only the most recent update being viewable:

```
struct node* getnewnode(char *s,int p){
    struct node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));   // don't cast return value of malloc
    newnode->string = strdup(s);   // create copy of given string
    newnode->priority=p;
    newnode->next=NULL;

   return newnode;
}
```

Comment: the memory that i allocated while declaring `a[20]` here a is also a pointer to base address of array will that be lost during run time or overwritten by the 
next buffer
can i use malloc for string memory allocation because i know  about malloc very well and not about strdups ?
i am a beginner

Comment: @david12345 In that particular case no, because it's a local variable of `main` and will therefore be valid for the length of the program.  Had you called some other function which declared a local array, passed that array to `push`, then returned from the function, then you would have a pointer to invalid memory.

Comment: can i use dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @david12345 Yes, that's exactly what `strdup` is doing.  It's effectively a `malloc` of the proper size followed by `strcpy`.